# Libvirt Connect to XEN from Windows

Tags: virtualization, xen, libvirt

I have setup XEN on SLES12 and created few virtual machines. Using virsh I am able to connect to libvirt from linux but not from windows. I was trying:

```
# connect xen://hostname
# connect xen://hostname/system
# connect xen+tcp://hostname
# connect xen+tcp://hostname/system
```

I have recieved following error messages:

```
# connect xen+tcp://hostname    'Unable to connect to server at 'hostname:16509': Unknown error 107'
# connect xen://hostname        'error: Cannot read CA certificate '/usr/i686-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/etc/pki/CA/cacert.pem': No such file or directory'
```

Other commands stated above produce same errors. I runned `netstat` and I cannot find port number 16509. I assume that when I connect from linux it uses different port(?) as there is no problem with that. the only difference is that from linux I use ssh connection:

```
 # connect xen+ssh://root@hostname
```

Any ideas will be appriciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s likely that your libvirtd is not listening to the **TCP** port. You must have –listen option while running the libvirtd.

Check following [link](http://www.doublecloud.org/2013/06/managing-kvm-with-libvirt-in-java-step-by-step-tutorial/)

Additionally you may need to modify /etc/libvirt/libvirtd.conf

```
listen_tls = 0 #it's enabled by default. To disable it, set it to be zero
listen_tcp = 1
tcp_port="16509"
listen_addr="192.168.45.22"
# tcp_auth = "sasl"
auth_tcp = "none"
# /usr/sbin/libvirtd –listen
```

Comment: Configuring libvirtd.conf solved the problem. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use command libvirtd -d 
It will create libvirtd deamon 
and then use libvirtd --listen to make libvirtd listen on TCP port.

Comment: Running libvirtd -d gave me following warning `virGetHostname:654 : getaddrinfo failed for 'linux-xlys': Name or service not known` and the error msg: `erorr: Unable to obtain pidfile. Check /var/log/messages  or run without --deamon for more info`